# Hopf Lemma for strong solutions

Tags: elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

The Hopf lemma still holds for strong solutions? Let $u\in W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $p>n$ such that $\Delta u + c(x) u\le 0$. If $u(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$ is smooth and $c\in C(\overline\Omega)$, then we have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0)>0$ for all $x_0\in\partial\Omega$.

It also holds for parabolic equations? Let $u\in C^1([0, T]; L^p(\Omega)) \cap C([0, T]; W^{2,p}(\Omega)\cap W_0^{1,p}(\Omega))$ with $p>n$ such that $\Delta u + c(x) u-u_t\le 0$. If $u(x, t)>0$ for all $(x, t)\in\Omega\times[0, T]$ and $\partial\Omega$ is smooth and $c\in C(\overline\Omega)$, then we have that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0, t)>0$ for all $(x_0, t)\in\partial\Omega\times(0, T]$.